# DataCache constructor not accessible on staging server; works fine locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-caching

I am using Azure's Cache Service preview, following their [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn386135.aspx). Things work great locally using IIS Express. However, when I deploy to the staging server, I receive the following error:

`Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.DataCache(string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

I am initializing `DataCache` with the following code, which throws the above error:

```
_cache = new DataCache("cacheName", "configurationName");
```

I am using the Azure Cache NuGet package and all the DLLs look correct in the bin directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a conflict with the AppFabric role feature which was installed on the staging server (Windows 2008 R2). Once that feature was removed, the Azure Cache worked fine.